# Deleting a view via its right-click dialog menu

Tags: android

I'm having trouble finding an approach that works for this.

I have a TextView within a LinearLayout which is created programmatically as needed. It has a right-click context menu which summons a dialog with which I want to allow the user to delete the TextView. So the flow goes right-click TextView A -> Dialog -> Delete -> Chooses to delete TextView.

However, I've not been able to find an approach with which I can locate and reference the original TextView which was right-clicked on.

The Context Menu and Dialog code I have are as follows:

```
   @Override  
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose your Fate:");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove task from schedule");  
   }

   @Override  
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
       if(item.getTitle()=="Remove task from schedule") {createDeleteTaskAlert(item.getActionView());}  
       else {return false;}  
       return true;  
   }  

   private void createDeleteTaskAlert(View view){
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
       alertDialog.setTitle("Delete Task");
       alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
       alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

/**Code to target and delete original TextView View goes here**/

            }
       });
       alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            }
       });
       alertDialog.create().show();
```

I apologize for the vagueness of this, but none of the approaches I've tried have been able to fulfill my need here, and I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a class member variable to hold the TextView being acted upon, you can do the following. Only the relevant bits are shown; the added lines have been tagged with a comment.

Add a member variable to your class definition:

```
private View theView = null;                                   // Line added
```

Set that member to the TextView whose context menu was opened:

```
@Override  
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     theView = v;                                              // Line added
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose your Fate:");  
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove task from schedule");  
}
```

Do the delete:

```
private void createDeleteTaskAlert(final View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete Task");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) theView.getParent();   // Line added
             vg.removeView(theView);                           // Line added
         }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
         }
    });
    alertDialog.create().show();
}
```

This assumes that the view has a parent ViewGroup. Most of the container objects are Viewgroups, but perhaps a sanity check (just to make sure) should be added. There may be a way to pass the view down through the call stack, but I'll leave that for someone else to figure out.

Comment: I thought about taking this approach but it seemed inelegant. I was looking for a way to access the earlier View variable, some way to functionally refer to the calling view. I tried making the createDeleteTaskAlert View final, but while that removed some compiler errors, it didn't work properly. It may just be that there's no inherent functional way to do it though, in which case I'll take the route you suggested.

Comment: I don't care much for the disconnected approach either. It's nearly the same thing as using global variables. But the original view gets lost along the path from view to context menu to alert dialog to dialog button. Getting the view passed down would probably require extending the classes and interfaces down that chain. My laziness side won out over my purist side :-) .

Comment: Agreed completely with you there =) I've run into a few situations since posting where I've needed to do this. Annoying, but such is life.

Comment: If this is the route you end up deciding as the best course of action, consider bumping it or marking it as the correct answer to help others know. If you later find a better solution to your original question, then you should add that as an answer and move your acceptance mark to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your deletable views in a `ViewGroup`, so you can manage them and for instance removing them with:

```
 ViewGroup.removeView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method:

```
public void deleteView(int id) {
    View v = (View) holderView.findViewById(id);
    holderView.removeView(v);
```

}

Where holderView is whatever the ViewGroup which holds your views is (ie whatever holds all the text views the user can select).

and in:

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

/**Code to target and delete original TextView View goes here**/
                 dialog.dismiss();
                 deleteView(id);
            }
       });
```

Should do it.

That said - I personally think this is a very cumbersome way to do this kind of thing.  If you look at modern android it is typical to assign this type of functionality to right/left swipe gestures, or long presses.  You might consider looking at that approach.

Comment: That's definitely a possibility, turning the option into a left- or right-swipe. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for the input.